# How to handle SystemVerilog-specific types in c and vice-versa?

Tags: system-verilog

As I know, in systemverilog, there are no char type and string.
SystemVerilog-specific types, including packed types (arrays, structures, unions), 2-state or 4-state, which have no natural correspondence in C.

if we use the char or string in c, How to handle SystemVerilog-specific types in c and vice-versa?

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation for "DPI-C" users is that unless you need access to 4-state values, keep your arguments C-compatible. That means using only `int`s, `byte`s(char), unpacked array/structs of ints/bytes, or strings(char *) across the language boundary.

Modelsim/Questa has a switch `-dpiheader filename` you should use when compiling your code that generates the proper C argument types for DPI-C routines. Your C code should `include this file to make sure your C code matches the required prototypes. That way you get a compiler error if they don't, instead of accessing garbage or corrupting data.

Answer (score 1):

An SV `string` input (to C) is a `const char *`. An SV `string` output or inout (from C) is a `const char **`.

As you might imagine, 4-state types are more complicated:

```
              SV TYPE - C TYPE
                logic - svLogic
packed array of logic - svLogicVecVal *
       unpacked array - svOpenArrayHandle
```

`svLogic`, `svLogicVecVal` and `svOpenArrayHandle` are types in `svdpi.h`. `svLogic` is typedef of an `unsigned char`, which can take the values `sv_0`, `sv_1`, `sv_x`, and `sv_z`, which are macros defined in `svdpi.h`. `svLogicVecVal` is a `struct` with two fields: `aval` and `bval`. `aval` and `bval` are 32-bit `int`s (canonical form). (In IUS, `aval` and `bval` are called `a` and `b`.)

Passing unpacked arrays using `svOpenArrayHandle` is much more complicated.

I don't know how to pass `struct`s or `union`s or even if it is possible. (Though to pass such a thing to C I guess you could do a bit-stream cast, but that is going to be messy).